# how to break down the admin app in django.contrib.auth to understand its working

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have been working with django for nearly 3 months and have been customizingadmin templates only. If I wanted to add any elements like buttons or some charts I extend the base.html, and then serve the extending template with another view inside my app(say Blog). But I want to customize my admin as much as possible but don't know how to do it. I have read the docs and it just gives snippets.

So to summarize, I want to create the admin site for my own blog right from scratch to understand the admin app in the contrib package in more detail.

Comment: What would likely be the best way to do what you want to is to just make a django app and call it something meaning full but different then admin for example `myadmin`. Then create all the functionality you want in the app there. Once you have it working just the way you want it to change the line in your `urls.py` file so `/admin` points to your app rather then the default admin interface.

Comment: Implementing the required functionality like a landing page or some data processing for charts is no the main problem that I am facing here. For e.g. I have been looking at the models of auth app which then uses the admin to register it. BUt then there are these AbstractBaseUser classes and Option classes used in there that I don't understand clearly. My question was if I want to implement something like that on my own or atleast learn how its done in the contrib package how do I go on about doing so?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what your desired outcome is because the current question kind of touches on a number of large complex topics. If we can narrow it down maybe I can come up with an answer that will meet your needs.

Comment: For eg I have been trying to create a custom user model extending the abstract base class. But what I have also been trying to do is extend modelbase to create a custom metaclass but add my own fields in it.

Comment: following the above comment.sorry i pressed enter by mistake. So when I do the above, I dont know which other module gets affected when I make this change. So thats what I meant to ask. If I could break down the admin app properly I can then know where I can make the appropriate changes(like the one mentioned in the previous comment) and not affect any other modules.

Comment: Personally I have never overridernen the Django User model because I don't like doing that kind of thing. It feels wrong to me. There is a lot to read and go over if its something you really want to do. All the information is in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model and the source code. I suggest you really read over this a couple of times before doing it or just extend the user model.

Comment: Here is a link to the github source code for that class. I find that if I'm having problems with the documentation the code clears it up https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L299